# How do I include the name of type parameter T in the summary of a generic method?

Tags: java

I want to do something like:

```
public class myClass<T> {
    /**
    returns a {class name of T}
    */
    public T getT() {
        return new T();
    }
}
```

I would like to replace "{Class Name of T}" with whatever T's classname is when the description shows up in vscode or another IDE like this:[image]

Comment: In general, the Javadoc tool doesn't allow you to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Java type erasure is going to require you pass a `Class<T>` somewhere in order to get a new `T` instance. Java class names start with a capital letter. As for your Javadoc, you could do something like `@returns a new T instance`. For example,

```
public class MyClass<T> {
    private Class<T> cls;
    public MyClass(Class<T> cls) {
        this.cls = cls;
    }
    
    /**
     * @returns a new T instance.
     * @throws IllegalAccessException 
     * @throws InstantiationException 
     * @throws SecurityException 
     * @throws NoSuchMethodException 
     * @throws InvocationTargetException 
     * @throws IllegalArgumentException 
    */
    public T getT() throws InstantiationException, 
            IllegalAccessException, IllegalArgumentException, 
            InvocationTargetException, NoSuchMethodException, 
            SecurityException {
        return cls.getConstructor().newInstance();
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think this addresses the OP's question, which is how to make the Javadoc substitute the appropriate value for T when viewed; it doesn't sound like the OP is asking about `new T()`.  (I don't believe what they're asking is possible, but in that case, we should say so.)